# how to get maximum value from specific .csv column

Tags: java

[Column FJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3MNJ.png)I try to get max value from specific column .. but I have problem with split method .. when I split by " *" or "\s*" it throw me this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."

But when I split with "," it gives me a value but not the max value .. where is the problem ..thanks in advance..

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //csv file containing data
        String strFile = "C:\\Users\\R2.csv";
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
        String [] nextLine = reader.readNext();

        String[] values = nextLine[165].split(","); // (" *") or ("\\s*")
        double[] maxValues = {0};
        for (int  i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            //check the max value
            double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);

            if(currentValue > maxValues[i] ) {
                maxValues[i] = currentValue;
                System.out.println( maxValues[i]);
            }
        } 
    }catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

new code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          //csv file containing data
          String strFile = "C:\\Users\\R2.csv";
          CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
          String [] nextLine;
          while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            String[] values = nextLine[165].split(",");
             double[] maxValues = {0};
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                 //check the max value
                double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);

            if(currentValue > maxValues[i] ) {
                maxValues[i] = currentValue;
                System.out.println( maxValues[i]);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException ie)
    {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an array of `maxValues` with only 1 value then attempting to change it at `maxValues[i]`.  How are you not getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: it doesn't throw me any exception !

Comment: If `i` is ever greater than `0` it will.  You are clearing doing something really wrong here that is not included in your code.  You also do not declare `int i = 0` in the loop, you just have it as `i`.

Comment: its just a part of code .. I declared  int i ;  as static  in my class

Comment: Post your `int i` declaration, I don't know why you would make a loop counter `static`, but if you made it `static final` that would be why you are not getting an exception because it doesn't even change.

Comment: I add it to the code .. now it miss only declaration of class ..

Comment: A short mockup of the first few lines of the CSV would help, as well as what you expect to happen.

Comment: `values` will obviously always contain one element since OP is trying to split a _column_ by “,” which will return an array with the column itself. Why are you not looping over all rows?

Comment: I have to work with huge csv (10080 lines)

Comment: Well how can you find the max value if you only look at the first row?

Comment: Joakim Danielson .. I need only the max value of one column elements thats why .. and I think its looping over all column values .. because String[] values get all elements splited .

Comment: Then please show an example of what the column at index 165 contains so we can understand what you mean and help you

Comment: Joakim Danielson  I added immage of my csv exemple  the column 165 is the column FJ  ..   the value I get is 0.05 and its the Min value !!

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] nextLine = reader.readNext();
```

The above line reads just one line of the csv, not the entire column. To compute the max, you will need to parse through the entire csv, i.e you will need to read the file until the file ends, store each column value in the desired column and use an efficient data structure to find the max of the column .Also , you dont need to split values by commas, csv reader already does that for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //csv file containing data
        String strFile = "C:\\Users\\R2.csv";
        String[] nextRecord;
        Double maxValue = 0;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
        while ((nextRecord = reader.readNext()) != null) {

           Double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(nextRecord[165]);
           if(currentValue> maxValue) {
              maxValue = currentValue 
           }
        }
     }catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // do error handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer , you are right because I changed my code and I didn't pay attention I will update my code to get all column elements .. can you show me how can I use stacks ti find ax value ..

Comment: Actually you'll not need stacks to find max. Just a temp variable will do.

Comment: your code seems almost when I println(maxValue) it gives me fives values  !!(0.05/
0.08/
0.1/
0.12/
0.13)   the max value is 0.13 and the min one is 0.05

Comment: are you rinting the max value inside the while loop or outside?

Comment: thank you my friend .. I got also your approach .. its working

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all lines of the file and compare the content of column 165 to be able to determine the max value in that column

```
String strFile = "C:\\Users\\R2.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));

String [] nextLine = null;
double maxValue = -1.0;

while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    String col165 = nextLine[165];
    double value = Double.parseDouble(col165);
    maxValue = value > maxValue ? value : maxValue;
}

System.out.println(“The max value is “ + maxValue);
```

if you want to continue looping even if the parsing fails you could do something like

```
try {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(col165);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    value = -1.0;
}
```

Note that -1.0 is just a value I selected judged by the sample, you might want to define a better minimum value to use.

Comment: thanks for answer , you are right because I changed my code and I didn't pay attention I update my code to get all column elements .. I will try what you suggested

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me all column elements  when I println(maxValue) !

Comment: @Khaaled maxValue is a double so it contains only one value. Did you really try my code exactly as I wrote it?

Comment: yes my friend I try it as you wrote exactly .. but it gives me all column elements ..

Comment: @Khaaled It can not do that unless you have the println inside the loop instead of after the loop.

Comment: my System.out.println( maxValue); is inside the loop !

Comment: @Khaaled But you need to let the program control all the rows before it knows what the max value is so there is no point in printing inside the loop. Please try to understand my code and what it does